# How do I invoke a UI method from a Systems.Timers thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a windows form application.
I am supposed a create an SQL job, and execute it. The SQL job consists of around 9 steps and takes around 4 hours to complete.
I am supposed to display the status of the SQL job, in a datagridview, so that its not necessary to go to SQL server and monitor the events.

My code is as below

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Thread t1 = new Thread(FirstThread);
            t1.Start();
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 500;
            timer.Enabled = true;

            timer.Elapsed += timer1_Tick;
            timer.Start();
            t1.Join();


        }
 private void FirstThread()
        {

            // Creates a job
            // Invoke the job, via a bat file

        }
 private void checkStatus()
        {            
            // Checks the status of the job using the EXEC sp_helpjob @jobName='JobName'
            // Populate the status on the DataGridView
            // If the status of the job, eg. 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            int CurrentExecution = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Current_Execution_Status"]);
            if (CurrentExecution == 4)
                label1.Text = "Job is Over";
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            checkStatus();
        }
```

I run into CrossThread Operation Not valid error. Could anyone please let me know how to call the UI controls inside the System.Timer Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Control` or `Form`:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { label1.Text = "Job is Over"; });
```

Or [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) if you don't want to wait until the action ended:

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { label1.Text = "Job is Over"; });
```

Comment: Or call [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) ;-)

Comment: @UweKeim: Indeed. Updated.

Comment: Or use `SynchronizationContext`  or even better `async-await` ;)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: You are right. There are a lot of options. Sometimes too many :)

Comment: But even the datagridview shows the Cross Thread operation error, how do I populate data inside it.

Comment: @cmrhema: Invoke it the same way.

Comment: Should have updated long ago. Thank you. BeginInvoke works.